# Google Sheets IMPORTXML XPath - Imported Content is empty

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance

I'm attempting to parse the '**PEG Ratio**' value of a stock from Yahoo Finance into a Google Sheet, but seeing an error.

URL used: `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/key-statistics?p=ABBV`

Cell Expression used: `=IMPORTXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/key-statistics?p=ABBV", "//td[@data-reactid='132']")`

Error: '**#N/A**' value (*Error: Imported Content is empty*)

Value expected is 1.28 (at the time of posting this query) - from Yahoo Finance > Statistics tab > PEG Ratio table (td has a, attribute `data-reactid='132'` that I have attempted to filter in the query)

Can anyone help please? Here is a link to the sheet: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXR7jAX93SnhRAOp2BMnbGDMOoPxm_D6dz2ChUnVRxE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`IMPORTXML` can only read the HTML source of a website. Therefore, those elements and components of a website added dynamically will not be able to be retrieved by the `IMPORTXML` and thus `IMPORTXML` will interpret the tag to be with empty content.

## Possible workaround

Sometimes, in the JavaScript files of the website, you can find out the URL of the source of data being inserted dynamically but that is a tedious task to achieve.

Other option to get the desired value is to use other web scraping techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation that someone with limited Javascript knowledge can understand. I was hoping there would be a Google Sheets function I could use to scrape this information after seeing that I could load the page with Javascript turned off as suggested [in this SO answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665).

Comment: Hi ! Yes so after an hour testing with ```IMPORTXML``` and ```IMPORTHTML``` I could actually pull all the data but the one from the top table. Interestingly, I could pull the *Valuation Measures* title and the ones next to it. Also, from the SO answer you mentioned it states that *The Chrome's Inspect tool shows the parsed DOM; in other words the actual structure/content of the web page which could be dynamically modified by JavaScript code or browser extensions/plugins.*. I strongly believe this is the case here. Would you be open to a solution using a sheet Apps Script script?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have the liberty of using Google Sheets built-in functions. I haven't used Apps scripts but I'll look it up. As long as the solution doesn't involve installing any third party stuff, it should be okay. With my limited Javascript knowledge I thought if Javascript was turned off, it was static content that was being parsed.

Comment: Hi ! So after trying with Apps Script too using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and not be able to retrieve that specific part of the website, it has been clear to me that this part was inserted with a script and therefore it cannot be retrieved in a *vanilla* way. Hope this information helps you :)

Comment: Uh ohh :sad: I take it, it is not possible to scrape those values into a Google Sheet through a simple mechanism then because of the way Javascript inserts those values on the rendered page. Appreciate your efforts and time. I'll give it a few days so others have a chance to read and comment. I'll come back in a few days and mark your answer as accepted if there is are no comments from others.

Comment: Yes, I was also disappointed that IMPORTXML couldn't pull from that part of the page, or that there wasn't some other native way in Sheets to pull it, at least not that I could find...

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not what you want, but I was searching around, and found a Google Sheets Add-On that does manage to pull the "1.28" value from that page.  It is free for doing a very limited number of queries per month.  If interested, search for IMPORTFROMWEB in the GSuite Marketplace.

I only plugged in your URL and the same XPath that you used, so I was very surprised when the data showed up.  No idea how it works.

I apologise if mentioning an Add-On is not appropriate on SO.  But knowing that an add-on can get that data off the web page may encourage some other ideas on how to do it natively with Sheets.

[image: ImportFromWeb Add-On]

Comment: Thanks for sparing the time to look into this. It was encouraging indeed. At least the Add-On confirmed that the XPath was correct. For a newbie in this area, that is a tremendous morale booster!! I would like to steer clear from paid / proprietary / throttled solutions though.